# Why don't python interpreter use the file coding format for decoding?

Tags: python, python-unicode

The code bellow will cause an `UnicodeDecodeError`:

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-   
s="中文"                                 
u=u"123"                                            
u=s+u
```

I know it's because python interpreter is using `ascii` to decode `s`.

Why don't python interpreter use the file format(utf-8) for decoding?

Comment: what does `u = s.decode("utf8") + u` output?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/18034409/1860929

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implicit decoding *cannot* know what source encoding was used. That information is not stored with strings.

All that Python has after importing is a byte string with characters representing bytes in the range 0-255. You could have imported that string from another module, or read it from a file object, etc. The fact that the *parser* knew what encoding was used for those bytes doesn't even matter for plain byte strings.

As such, it is always better to decode bytes *explicitly*, rather than rely on the implicit decoding. Either make use a Unicode literal for `s` as well, or explicitly decode using `str.decode()`

```
u = s.decode('utf8') + u
```

Comment: I knew the difference between unicode and string, and I knew how to solve the problem I occurred. I just want to know why not python interpreter use the file format to decode a string to unicode. So I think this answer is best.

Answer (score 1):

The types of the 2 strings are different - the first is a normal string, second is a unicode string, hence the error.

So, instead of doing `s="中文"`, do as following to get unicode strings for both:

```
s=u"中文"
u=u"123"
u=s+u
```

Answer (score 1):

The code works perfectly fine on Python 3.

However, in Python 2, if you do not add a `u` before a string literal, you are constructing a string of bytes. When one wants to combine a string of bytes and a string of characters, one either has to decode the string of bytes, or encode the string of characters. Python 2.x opted for the former. In order to prevent accidents (for example, someone appending binary data to a user input and thus generating garbage), the Python developers chose `ascii` as the encoding for that conversion.

You can add a line

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

after the `#coding` declaration so that literals without `u` or `b` prefixes are always character and not byte literals.