# Extra "u" when converting from json to csv in python

Tags: python, json, csv, pandas

I try to convert from json to csv, But there is Extra letter "u" has been appeared before every word in list , i used pandas to read this csv data, 
this is my code :

```
import json
import csv
with open("train.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
with open("trainc.csv", "w") as file:
    csv_file = csv.writer(file)
    csv_file.writerow(data[0].keys())
    for item in data:
    csv_file.writerow(item.values())
import pandas as pd
train = pd.read_csv("trainc.csv", header=0)
```

As Example from json file, this is the first one :

```
{
    "id": 10259,
    "cuisine": "greek",
    "ingredients": [
      "romaine lettuce",
      "black olives",
      "grape tomatoes",
      "garlic",
      "pepper",
      "purple onion",
      "seasoning",
      "garbanzo beans",
      "feta cheese crumbles"
    ]
  }
```

I used this line to print ingredients

```
print train['ingredients'][0]
```

And when I printed the same record output was like that :

`[u'romaine lettuce', u'black olives', u'grape tomatoes', u'garlic', u'pepper', u'purple onion', u'seasoning', u'garbanzo beans', u'feta cheese crumbles']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `u` is not in your string. It just says that the type of data is [unicode](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html).

```
for x in train['ingredients'][0]:
     print x
```

You see that there in no extra `u` in your data.

[Python str vs unicode types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034272/python-str-vs-unicode-types)
http://www.diveintopython.net/xml_processing/unicode.html

Comment: But when i try to process over (ingredients) , it enters in processing as a part of string !!
what should i do to prevent that ? 
@sudomakeinstall2

Comment: Don't print the list, print the strings inside the list

Comment: Why do u want to prevent that? What is the problem?

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 I used you code and it works fine without u :)) .

Comment: @iayork  I used print as indication for my process

Comment: @MohammedKhalifa I strongly recommend you to read about `unicode` in python.