# python pandas read_cvs load utf-8

Tags: python, csv, pandas, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to `read_csv` a csv file with cyrillic charactres with [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

```
import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv('dataset.csv', delimiter='\|\|', engine='python', encoding='utf-8')
print type(data.name[0])

<type 'str'>
```

Here, I am expecting to get `unicode` as with

```
print type(u'hello')

<type 'unicode'>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Python is duck-typed. You should never ask for what type an object is. This being said, you need to provide some kind of example where you show what you have and what your desired output is. Your code appears correct AFAIK

Comment: I don't know how pandas implements the `read_csv` method, but if it uses the std.lib. `csv` module, then the solution to this probably isn't trivial, because Python 2's `csv` doesn't support decoding files (which is quite sad, in fact). One more reason to switch to Python 3 now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Unicode is *uncoded* text. UTF-8 is a way of *encoding* unicode characters. When pandas imports your utf-8 encoded text, it converts it to python `str` type, which is *decoded* text. In python 3, the `str` type is the same as unicode.

For a more in-depth understanding, see:

1. [UTF-8 vs Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643694/utf-8-vs-unicode)
2. [Python str vs Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034272/python-str-vs-unicode-types)

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification.

Comment: The OP is apparently using Python 2 (see the print statement). In Python 2, *decoded* (I think that's what you mean by “uncoded”) text is of type `unicode`. So, apparently, pandas did **not** properly decode the input text.

Comment: Fair point... I'm not sure how this works in python 2. Any ideas @lenz?

Comment: Looking at [pandas' `read_csv` documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), I strongly suspect that they're using the std.lib. `csv` module (because of the keywords "quoting", "quotechar" etc.). This means that it needs a workaround in Python 2, such as decoding after parsing.