# Python2: what do str.encode() and unicode.decode() do?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8

From this question and its answers [Python str vs unicode types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034272/python-str-vs-unicode-types) I understood that `unicode.encode()` gives you `str` and `str.decode()` gives you `unicode`:

```
a = 'à'
ua = u'à'
print type(a)  # str
print type(ua)  # unicode
print ua.encode('utf-8') == a  # True
print a.decode('utf-8') == ua  # True
```

But I don't understand the purpose of `unicode.decode()` and `str.encode()` methods. What are they supposed to return? How can I use them? Both following lines are failing with `UnicodeDecodeError` or `UnicodeEncodeError`:

```
print ua.decode('utf-8')
print a.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Those methods (which were removed in Python 3 for good reasons) come from the fact that there is automatic coercion between `str` and `unicode`. In Python 2, those two types have the same interface. When you call `str.encode`, the `str` object is first coerced to `unicode` under the hood, and then encoded to `str`. Analogously for `unicode.decode`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR Using `unicode.decode` and `str.encode` means you aren't using the right types to represent your data. The methods on the equivalent types in Python 3 don't even exist.

---

A `unicode` value is a single Unicode code point: an integer *interpreted* as a particular character. A `str`, on the other hand, is a sequence of bytes.

For example, `à` is Unicode code point U+00E0. The UTF-8 encoding represents it with a *pair* of bytes,  0xC3 and 0xA0.

The `unicode.encode` method takes a Unicode string (a sequence of code points) and returns the byte-level encoding of each code point as a single byte string.

```
>>> ua.encode('utf-8')
'\xc3\xa0'
```

`str.decode` takes a byte string and attempts to produce the equivalent Unicode value.

```
>>> '\xc3\xa0'.decode('utf-8')
u'\xe0'
```

(`u'\xe0'` is equivalent to `u'à'`).

---

As for your errors: Python 2 doesn't enforce a strict separation between how `unicode` and `str` are used. It doesn't really make *sense* to encode a `str` if it is already an encoded value, and it doesn't make sense to decode a `unicode` value because it's not encoded in the first place. Rather than pick apart exactly how the errors occur, I'll just point out that in Python 3, there are two types: `bytes` is a string of bytes (corresponding to Python 2 `str`), and `str` is a Unicode string (corresponding to Python 2 `unicode`). The "nonsensical" methods don't even *exist* in Python 3:

```
>>> bytes.encode
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'bytes' has no attribute 'encode'
>>> str.decode
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'str' has no attribute 'decode'
```

So your attempts that raised `Unicode*Error` exceptions before now would simply raise an `AttributeError`.

If you are stuck supporting Python 2, just follow these rules:

- `unicode` is for *text*
- `str` is for binary data
- `unicode.encode` produces a `str` value
- `str.decode` produces a `unicode` value
- If you find yourself trying to call `str.encode`, you are using the wrong type.
- If you find yourself trying to call `unicode.decode`, you are using the wrong type.