# Remove double curly braces or transform a string to raw string literal in Ansible

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, netbox

I imported data in Ansible from a csv file and wanted to convert the String from csv file to a raw in Ansible.

Ansible:

`parent_region: "{{ parent_region }}"` ansible will interpret this as `"parent_region": "1933"`.

Is there a way to remove the curly braces and make ansible interpret the code as `"parent_region": 1933` ???

any help is appreciated!

**EDIT**  I need the variable to be `raw` since `parent_region` field in Netbox's `netbox_region` only accepts `raw`. Here is the official [documention](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/netbox/netbox/netbox_region_module.html).

Comment: If you are using a template you could try with `parent_region: {{ parent_region }}`

Comment: @garylopez Tried that aswell, but it gives out an error `ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  found unacceptable key (unhashable type: 'AnsibleMapping')
The offending line appears to be:

#      parent_region: "{{ parent_region }}"
      parent_region: {{ parent_region }}
                      ^ here`

Comment: @VladimirBotka My bad, already changed the title.

Answer (score 1):

Use [7.3.2. Single-Quoted Style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2788097). Quoting:

| *the “\” and “"” characters may be freely used.*

For example, given the variable

```yaml
parent_region: "1933"
```

the tasks below

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        parent_region: 'r"{{ parent_region }}"'
    - debug:
        var: parent_region
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ parent_region|type_debug }}"
```

give (the quotes are part of the string)

```yaml
  parent_region: r"1933"
  msg: str
```

---

The default type in Ansible (Python3) is a Unicode string, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        parent_region: "1933"
    - debug:
        var: parent_region
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ parent_region|type_debug }}"
```

give (the quotes are NOT part of the string)

```yaml
  parent_region: '1933'
  msg: AnsibleUnicode
```

---

You can create a custom filter and choose the [encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#encodings-and-unicode), e.g.

```py
shell> cat filter_plugins/python_encode.py

def python_encode(s, encoding):
    return s.encode(encoding)

class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'python_encode': python_encode,
        }
```

then the tasks

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        parent_region: "{{ parent_region|python_encode('raw_unicode_escape') }}"
    - debug:
        var: parent_region
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ parent_region|type_debug }}"
```

give

```yaml
  parent_region: b'1933'
  msg: str
```

See [Python str vs unicode types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034272/python-str-vs-unicode-types/18034409).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the variable to an integer using the `int` filter:

```
parent_region: "{{ parent_region | int }}"
```

Comment: I need the variable to be `raw`, so is there a filter as well to make it raw?. My bad for not specifying it, will edit the question.